# NodeJS - How can I check if a MySQL result is undefined/empty?

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

Does anyone know how to check if a NodeJS MySQL result is null/empty? What I'm trying to do is (very succinctly explained) to check if result 5 is empty or not, and if it's not, then execute an action (console.log in this case).

This is the code without all the details, to simplify things, but when executing it I get that "result" is not defined

```js
           con.query("SELECT tag, message FROM list1", function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
              console.log('Error: ' + err)
            }
          });
        
          if(!result[5] == undefined) {
              console.log('Result 5 exists')
          }
```

Comment: Because `result[5]` is outside the callback scope

Comment: Uh, yeah, I'm dumb. Thanks a lot! I didn't notice before cause the real code is so big that it was kinda complicated to realize that ^^

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use this pattern.

```js
con.query('SELECT tag, message FROM list1', [info] function(err, row, fields) {
  if(err) {
    return console.log('Error1');
  } else if (!row.length) {                                                   
    return console.log('Error2');
  } else if (!row[0].something) {
    return console.log('Error3');
  }

  console.log('Works');
})
```

It's using a ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) check for row[0]. something which will return false if the value is undefined, null or an empty string. It also fixes the injection attack vector.

Answer (score 0):

In the if statement at the bottom, use `typeof result[5] !== 'undefined'`.

Your current method checks if the value of result[5] is equal to undefined, but will crash if result[5] does not exist. Checking the type will return 'undefined' if the variable does not exist.

edited code:

```
con.query("SELECT tag, message FROM list1", function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    }
});
    
if(typeof result[5] !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('Result 5 exists');
}
```